# How many times has a piano been on-screen in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek

For some reason, it seems to me that unlike other instruments, pianos aren't that common in *Star Trek.* I remember Voyager's Holographic Doctor playing a jazz piece (I think) on a piano in a holodeck, and Seven learning to play piano from him; I also remember that recently, in a *Star Trek: DISCO* episode, Adira played a melody on a piano. Are there any other times that a piano was played or even seen in an episode?
Could there possibly be a reason why pianos aren't so common in *Star Trek?* Or is it that they appear more often than I thought?

Comment: Full size or does that roll-out 'piano' count? I'd say out of universe they're just a pain in the arse to get on set without a damn good reason.

Comment: "unlike other instruments". Are other instruments really shown that much more? Also, it's not like I see pianos in real life that often

Comment: In Star Trek Voyager there is an episode where the crew is stuck on the holodeck in a world war 2 scenario. The crew is part of the French resistance in a small town who own a bar of sorts. If memory serves Seven is here seen singing in front of a man playing the piano.

Comment: Now I'm trying to remember whether Spock was sitting at a piano or a harpsichord when he announced his hypothesis that the man currently hosting the landing party in his parlor was in fact Bach, and probably Leonardo da Vinci too.

Comment: The scene where Seven is learning piano, she was taught by Chakotay [(VOY: Human Error)](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Human_Error_(episode)). The doctor and Seven sang together.

Comment: Do you include harpsichord?  Trelayne had one of those...

Comment: Star trek voyager s5 episode 21 10:30. A piano is being played on the holodeck bar program.

Comment: @IvoBeckers Perhaps they just appeared to be rare in _Star Trek_ for me because I see them every day of my life.

Comment: Does the sound of a piano being played count as well, or only where they're visible?

Comment: @Mast I think both could work, but I'm more interested in when a piano appeared on screen.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I wouldn't mind hearing about harpsichords in _Star Trek,_ but I'm looking more specifically for pianos.

Comment: Also, why is it that this question received four downvotes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Piano) is to believed, the piano is seen or referenced 15 times. However, the actual count is higher:

- Twice in *TOS* (including movies)
- Three times in *The Next Generation* (including movies)
- Six times in *Deep Space 9*
- At least 3 times in *Voyager*

  - Unnamed holodeck location, Seven & Chakotay in [Human Error](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Human_Error_(episode)) [(pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URGRu.jpg).
  - Le Coeur de Lion (holodeck), played by an unknown hologram accompanied by Seven singing in [The Killing Game](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com./wiki/The_Killing_Game_(episode)) [(pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFWrp.jpg)
  - Chez Sandríne, at least shown twice in the episode [Someone to Watch Over Me](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Someone_to_Watch_Over_Me_(episode)) (holodeck, program Paris 3), possibly in other episodes as well [(pic)](https://imgur.com/dvvEXBY.jpg). Later in the same episode, the Doctor plays the piano as well [(pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6S5GX.jpg).
- Twice in *Enterprise*
- Once in *Discovery*

Compare to four uses of trumpet, six of trombone, eight of guitar, 12 of Vulcan lute, and two of the banjo.

Comment: this answer is little more than a link to a wiki - better would be to include a few screenshots or at least reference the episodes indicated :)

Comment: @NKCampbell I'm not sure if this sort of question needs much more than that though. Perhaps it could answer the why as well, but that's definitely outside the scope of what was asked

Comment: I sort of suspect there were a few pianos in the background in holodeck scenes in TNG that aren't mentioned there. (They quite often seemed to end up in simulations of 20th century jazz bars, so it would make sense if there was a piano.) I don't know any specific examples, though.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - I'm just saying it would be nice to at least include the episode / film names :)

Comment: And don't forget Harry Kim's clarinet.

Comment: @Nathaniel Definitely a few missing - one I can think of is season 1 with the Binars where they lure Riker into the holodeck to tangle him up with Minuet.  There he plays with a Jazz band that includes a piano (which he specifically asks for when asking the computer to generate a band).

Comment: I could swear I've seen more than 1 piano in Voyager. Tom's bar definitely had one (Chez Sandrine), there's a piano in the WWII episode with the Hirogen and then there's Human Error, Seven playing with Chakotay. That's on top of the reference Memory Alpha makes of the Doctor.

Comment: Only 6 in DS9?  I find that to be rather unlikely.  Just the Vic Fontaine episodes alone would be 7 episodes, and that's not counting the one in Papa Sisko's restaurant.

Comment: There’s a piano in the saloon in “A Fistful of Datas” (TNG S6E8). I don’t see that mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Trelane played a harpsichord in the TOS: *Squire of Gothos* - though it's been speculated that the instrument shown was actually a piano.

Comment: I believe there was also a piano in the saloon in TOS: *Spectre of the Gun*.

Comment: Clearly many more examples than in the linked article. Have converted the answer to community wiki - hopefully the additional examples can be added to give a better representation.

Comment: In particular, Spock plays the piano in "Requiem for Methuselah" (TOS 3.19)

Comment: And Data's violin!

Comment: *There. Are. Four. [Flutes].*

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad that they are much more common than they thought.

Comment: The DS9 pianos include: in Benny's apartment in *Far Beyond the Stars*, in Sisko's restaurant in *Image in the Sand* / *Shadows and Symbols*, at Vic's in *His Way* (and maybe in the background in other episodes featuring Vic's, but not mentioned by the script).

Answer (score 2):

In the TOS episode "Miri", the landing party chases Miri into a house.

And I think it is a piano in the house which is the subject of the lines:

> KIRK: How old is this thing?

> SPOCK: About three hundred years.

http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/12.htm

If that is correct, that is one more example of a piano in *Star Trek*.

Comment: Rewatched the relevant part of ST:TOS "Miri" and can confirm what Kirk is looking at when he says that line is a decrepit old piano, although I can't find a clip online as evidence (and the steaming service I used certainly won't let me capture it myself).